# What justified consciousness is an experience and not an thing?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, epistemology, metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind, consciousness

No philosophers has justified that consciousnesses can be measured. Many philosophers have tried to describe the mind, but are there any specific scholars who describe justified methods to describe that consciousness is an experience and not a thing.

Some source came up like Heidegger, Husserl and Kant.

A thing is an object which is observed by an entity.
An experience is, that what the subject is experiencing.

Comment: husserl called his phenomenology a "science" but i'd guess that "measure" is the wrong term, cos he was concerned with essences (colours have shape, i think is one?) not quantities. over a decade ago, there was a fairly new movement in contemporary psychology, trying to incorporate phenomenological ideas more, but i'm not sure how it fared. aside from that, self report, observation of behaviour, and studies of the brain, seem to be the options. philosophers, rather than scientists, would be better set to learn from, be informed by, these scientific methods, than perform them, i'd guess

Comment: Even if it is a phenomena, if it is correct word to use on consciousness, then what defines the definition of consciousness. Many philosophers has tried to understand the mind, but can people in general speak of "people live in different states of consciousness", as you already said Husserl for example describe it not in quantifiable things.

Comment: Turing 1950 advances the proposition that if something acts intelligent, it should be regarded as intelligent. That's his famous Turing test. Well worth your time to read. https://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/471/papers/turing.pdf

Comment: Consciousness is not detectable in physics. This is what allows some speculators to claim it doesn't exist apart from brain-functions. . .

Comment: the question is less broad now but maybe too vague? what do you mean by a "thing"?

Comment: No philosopher has ever suggested that consciouness can be measured as far as I know. If they suggested this they'd have to explain how it could be done. .

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to ask 'How to measure', first you should confirm whether consciousness is a thing like light, waves, radiation etc.  If you are quite sure about it, you may try to search a tool for measuring it.

We don't even know whether consciousness is zero dimensional, infinite dimensional or something more than these.  Those who could realize consciousness would smile if they were asked this question.

If one says, from his limited knowledge, that consciousness is in living things only, we can't blame anyone.  But the truth is that consciousness is everywhere.  If so, what tool can we use to measure a thing that is present everywhere?!!  So, IMHO, we'd better 'realize' consciousness before trying to search a tool for measuring that 'unknown' thing.

http://www.mind-your-reality.com/universal_mind.html